# intersections between 3d planes

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The intersection of the planes defined by
$v \bullet \begin{pmatrix} 8 \\ 1 \\ -12 \end{pmatrix} = 35$
and
$v \bullet \begin{pmatrix} 6 \\ 7 \\ -9 \end{pmatrix} = 70$
is a line. Find an equation of this line.

What I did was I replaced v with $\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}$, before bashing it out, which resulted in $2x-y-3z=0$. However, how do I proceed from here?

Comment: There's certainly a mistake somewhere, in that the common solution set of the two initial equations (a line) is not the same as the solution set of the single equation you found (a plane). Could you please explain how you got $2x - y - 3z = 0$, and particularly how you "lost" an equation? Also, have you seen a systematic method for solving systems of linear equations?

Answer (score 1):

take $z=\lambda$ and solve for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $\lambda$ . You will get the required line. ($y=0; \frac{x}{3}=\frac{z}{2}$)

Comment: Does it mean to solve in terms of z? And what does $\lambda$ mean?

Comment: $\lambda$ is some constant which you have to eliminate in the end. Equation of line in 3d is on form $\frac{x-a}{b}=\frac{y-c}{d}=\frac{z-e}{f}$ . All you need to do is to find relationship among$x,y,y$. If you want you can also solve in terms of any other variable.

Answer (score 0):

$2x-y-3z=0$ is your plane. Any coordinate which satisfies this formula is a coordinate that exists in the plane. Notice how the question asks for an equation of this line, the equation you have there is such an equation.

So basically you don't precede. Unless you want to plot it, which could you help you see that this is an equation of a line in 3-D space.